# std::expm1(z) for complex z?

Tags: c++, precision

The standard C++ library provides `std::expm1(x)` only for real `x`. Is there an implementation of `std::expm1(z)` for complex `z`?

Comment: I don't see an analog of `std::expm1` but there is a [`std::exp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/exp) in the `<complex>` library that can handle complex numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the standard library, no.

Might be worth proposing it for inclusion in a future version.

Comment: I suspected the standard library didn't provide it. I am looking for an alternative implementation somewhere else. Don't delete this, though, since it confirms my suspicion (+1).

Comment: @becko: Oh, well software/library recommendations are off-topic, as I'm sure you know. So this answer is all I can give you.

Comment: Hmmm, in that case I have to accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Not that I would be the type of person to support requests for 3rd party libraries.... but [C-XSC](http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/org/WRST/xsc/cxsc/apidoc/html/index.html) seems to have implemented `expm1` for complex types, as well as other methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
exp(a + i*b) - 1
= exp(a) * (cos(b) + j*sin(b)) - 1
= exp(a)*cos(b)-1 + j*exp(a)*sin(b)
= (exp(a)-1)*cos(b) + (cos(b)-1) + j*exp(a)*sin(b)
=   expm1(a)*cos(b) + (cos(b)-1) + j*exp(a)*sin(b)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The only thing that will have accuracy problems (for small `b`) is the term highlighted, because then we would be taking the very tiny first term, adding `cos(b)`, which is almost 1 (i.e. relatively enormous), then subtracting 1. Doing this will ruin the accuracy of the first term, in general.

Luckily, computing pioneers have already ran into this problem and have given us a solution, called `cosm1(..)`, which implements `(cos(b)-1)` accurately for small `b`. For example, [here is an implementation in C that SciPy uses](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/cephes/unity.c). I can't see it in [`<cmath>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/), so it's probably considered too obscure.

Comment: Or you can replace `1 - cos(b)` with `2 * sin(b / 2) ^ 2`